# Magento2 add to cart always adds 2 items

Tags: magento2

Here is our site test.onepearl.co.uk/sherdley this magento version is 2.1.3 everything was working fine but now today when you click add to cart from the product page it adds 2 of the item to the cart.

Strange thing is it doesn't alway happen but around 80% of the time it goes wrong instead of adding 1× Item it adds 2 x item .

Does anyone know what causes this ?

Comment: I just tried your test site and added some products to the carts. It always add one item each time, so I don't see the problem you described. Have you tried to use another browser?

Comment: It's happening only on product page

Comment: I have had this before, Zefiryn answer should fix if you see where that second instance of the ajax binding is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 events fired on button click on product page, both are submitting the form. When you look at the source of the product page there are those 2 script tags:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#product_addtocart_form": {
        "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#product_addtocart_form": {
        "catalogAddToCart": {
            "bindSubmit": true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

They are binding 2 widgets to `#product_addtocart_form` element. Both those widgets hook into `submit` action in order to change standard post request to ajax request. Remove the one you actually do not need.

Comment: Thanks Zefiryn . That was the perfect soultion. I was using a theme that was adding the addto cart twice so I have commented it out and now all is good !!! thanks again