# Duplicate Product in Cart Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart, qty-increment

I have an issue in Magento 2.1.6. When I add the same product in cart it's  adding as a new line not update Qty of product.
The same issue in the mini cart also.

**Actual Result:**
Add as a separate product.

**Expected Result:**
Update Qty if exist same product.

[image: Mini Cart]

[image: Cart Page]

Comment: As I see, your product has options? A product has different options that will be added to cart separately.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh No there is not an option. All products are simple without any options.

Comment: Could you please share product URL so I can check at my system as well ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222253/magento2-add-to-cart-always-adds-2-items - This answer works for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for this issue but in my case I have a custom code running on the minicart

```
<preference for="\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart" type="\Vendor\QuickCart\Model\CustomerData\Cart"/>
```

In my case I'm extending the method `getSortedCartItems` and doing my own work in there.

So either the issue comes form a custom code broken there either you can analyse the getSortedCartItems from Magento Checkout and see what is happening.

Worst case scenario you can always extend the method to clean the returned array by yourself...even if for sure that's not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this file in core or overrated in your modules.

```
vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item.php
```

Please check and debug this function **representProduct()** responsible for merging and adding new items to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are adding some custom option so that product becomes differen.

In magento if you pass some custom option to the add to card process, it adds  new quote item in the database.

Check if some custom module make changes to the cart process with plugin or observer. Try disabling custom modules to see is this problem persist.